# Why does the Frame not appear in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a program that plays music based on notes that you put in. Everything was going swimmingly untill I tried to add different screens of the application. I have two frames, `songSelect` and `mainMenu`. I `lift()` the one that I want to display at that time. The only problem is, that nothing will appear.

Here is my code:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Music Creator")
root.geometry("300x230")
root.iconbitmap(default='favicon.ico')
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

mainMenu = Frame(root)
songSelect = Frame(root)

def raiseFrame(frame):
    frame.lift()

mainMenu.lift()

programName = Label(mainMenu, text="Music Creator", font=("Helvetica",20))

noteLabel = Label(mainMenu, text="Notes to play:")
tempoLabel = Label(mainMenu, text="Interval to play the notes at: (In seconds)")

noteEntry = Entry(mainMenu)
tempoEntry = Entry(mainMenu)

playButton = Button(mainMenu, text="Play", command=lambda: playNotes(noteEntry.get(),tempoEntry.get()))
loadButton = Button(mainMenu, text="Load", command=lambda: raiseFrame(songSelect))

programName.place(relx=0.5,y=25,anchor=CENTER)
noteLabel.place(relx=0.5,y=60,anchor=CENTER)
noteEntry.place(relx=0.5,y=90,anchor=CENTER)
tempoLabel.place(relx=0.5,y=130,anchor=CENTER)
tempoEntry.place(relx=0.5,y=160,anchor=CENTER)
playButton.place(relx=0.5,y=200,anchor=CENTER)
loadButton.place(x=10,y=40)

root.mainloop()
mainMenu.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use `place`, the frames don't resize to fit their contents. Therefore your frame is only one pixel tall and wide.

Comment: @Legodog5678: i recommend using grid or pack for the widgets inside the frames. Or, give the frames an explicit width and height. Grid and pack are almost always preferable to place.

Comment: I will set the frames explicit width and height. I would like to use `grid()`, but I cannot figure out how to center something with `grid()`. Could you shed some  light on this?